# Maven clean fails: The specified JRE installation does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a Maven project using Spring Initializr.

I just installed both JDK 10 and Eclipse Jee Oxygen.

I loaded the project into Eclipse.

When I go right click on the project -> Run as -> Maven clean, I get the following error:

> The specified JRE installation does not exist

What's the reason for that and how can I fix it?

What I've tried:

Going to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Add, then choosing the directory of the installed JDK 10, checking it instead of what had been selected (JRE-10).

It hasn't changed anything.

Comment: You loaded an existing project? Perhaps it explicitly chooses a JRE by name, and that name is not in your list. Check the Build Path of the project.

Comment: @Andreas yes, I did load an existing project. In Properties -> Java build path, there is a warning: "Build path entry is missing: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8". Additionally the JRE is existing there but there is a red error sign and it says "unbound".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573872/maven-clean-fails-the-specified-jre-installation-does-not-exist/50574013#comment88157356_50573872):

> In Properties -> Java build path, there is a warning: `Build path entry is missing: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8".`

Since the project has explicitly selected the Execution Environment named `JavaSE-1.8`, you need to ensure it has a compatible JRE:

- Open Window -> Preferences
- Select Java -> Installed JREs > Execution Environments
- Check a compatible JRE

If the Compatible JREs box is empty, check the Installed JREs page to ensure your have one.

[image]

Alternatively, go to the Properties > Java Build Path, select the Libraries tab, select the `JRE System Library` entry, click Edit, and change the explicit selection if which Java runtime to use.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in Run Configurations (right click project root in Eclipse Package Explorer view and select Run As/Run Configurations...), I forgot to select a JRE under the JRE tab of the Maven Build/Clean And Compile run configuration.